# SQL Date Padding

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to essentially return a list of days along with a count of how many user records were created on each day. This is easy until you want to include days with no record creations, of course. I'm no SQL expert, so I've cobbled the following together - it looks like it should work (syntax aside), but could anyone point me further in the right direction?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b. %Y") as reg_date, COUNT(*) as signups 
FROM `users` 
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT "20 Aug. 2015" as theDate UNION ALL
SELECT "21 Aug. 2015" as theDate UNION ALL
SELECT "22 Aug. 2015" as theDate UNION ALL
SELECT "23 Aug. 2015" as theDate UNION ALL
SELECT "24 Aug. 2015" as theDate UNION ALL
SELECT "25 Aug. 2015" as theDate UNION ALL
SELECT "26 Aug. 2015" as theDate UNION ALL
SELECT "27 Aug. 2015" as theDate UNION ALL
) 
AS dates ON `dates`.`theDate` = reg_date 
GROUP BY YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at), DAY(created_at))
```

This prompts a syntax error.

Comment: First remove the last `union all`  `SELECT "27 Aug. 2015" as theDate UNION ALL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query needs some fixing:

- For the `left join`, the dates need to be first.
- You need to aggregate by `thedate`.  Otherwise, you will get rows with `NULL`.
- You cannot use a column alias defined in the `SELECT` in the `ON` clause.
- You should express your date constants in the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format.

I think this query should work for you:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(thedate, "%d %b. %Y") as reg_date,
       COUNT(u.created_at) as signups 
FROM (SELECT date('2015-08-20') as thedate union all
      SELECT date('2015-08-21') as thedate union all
      SELECT date('2015-08-22') as thedate union all
      SELECT date('2015-08-23') as thedate union all
      SELECT date('2015-08-24') as thedate union all
      SELECT date('2015-08-25') as thedate union all
      SELECT date('2015-08-26') as thedate union all
      SELECT date('2015-08-27') as thedate
     ) dates left join
     users u
     ON dates.theDate = date(u.created_at) 
GROUP BY dates.theDate
ORDER BY reg_date;
```

Comment: Thanks so much; this does a lot of the job, but seems to stop returning rows after the first 0 signups. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @user1353810358 . . . I fixed the `group by` to follow the advice I give before the query.

Comment: Oh, thank you, sorry I misunderstood your advice on that point. The query works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

your code have a multiple syntactical errors.See following corrections and try

```
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b. %Y") as reg_date, COUNT(*) as 
signups FROM `users`

LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT "20 Aug. 2015" as theDate UNION ALL
SELECT "21 Aug. 2015" as theDate UNION ALL
SELECT "22 Aug. 2015" as theDate UNION ALL
SELECT "23 Aug. 2015" as theDate UNION ALL
SELECT "24 Aug. 2015" as theDate UNION ALL
SELECT "25 Aug. 2015" as theDate UNION ALL
SELECT "26 Aug. 2015" as theDate UNION ALL
SELECT "27 Aug. 2015" as theDate
) 
AS dates ON `dates`.`theDate` = DATE_FORMAT(`user`.created_at, "%d %b. %Y") 
GROUP BY YEAR(`user`.created_at), MONTH(`user`.created_at), DAY(`user`.created_at))
```